# how to copy aws s3 files to a particular folder in the same bucket using angular js

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

Anybody know Inside S3 how to copy files from one folder to another folder in a same bucket using angularjs.

Is it possible to copy and move the files inside the buckets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS JS SDK to achieve this.

Pl refer to this doc for more info

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property